# Looking to count zero values from right to left until non-zero values appears

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query, counting

I have a large table of monthly values.
I am looking to count the zero values from right to left, stopping once a non-zero value occurs.
I want the last column to display these values.

`| JAN | FEB | MAY | APR | MAY | JUN | Value I need |`
`Ben    |  10 |  10 |  10 |   0 |   0 |   0 | =3           |`
`Tim    |   0 |   0 |  10 |  10 |  10 |   0 | =1           |`
`Susan  |   0 |   0 |   5 |  10 |   0 |  10 | =0           |`
`Frank  |  10 |   0 |   0 |  10 |  10 |  10 | =0           |`

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Would an Apps Script solution be acceptable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need anything very sophisticated - just find last column which is non-zero:

```
=ArrayFormula(columns(B:G)-max(if(B2:G2>0,column(B:G)-column(A:A),0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,LEN(REGEXREPLACE(INDEX(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(VLOOKUP(A2:A, A2:G, TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B:G)), 1, 0)), 0)=0, 
 "♦", "♥")),,9^9)), "♥", , 0),,1), "^ .+| |#.+", ))))
```

[image: 0]